# How to get reference to a view of a fragment that's in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have a Fragment in a ViewPager, and I want to access a View in said Fragment in order to change its background from the FragmentActivity.

I've been trying with every answer related I could find. No luck yet. Any ideas?

-R

Comment: Do you mean you want to access a View inside of a Fragment from it's Parent activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get your fragment :

```
YourFrag frag = (YourFrag) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, pageNumber);
```

then you can get the views as usual

```
frag.getView().findViewById() ...
```

or however you like.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a function inside `ViewPager` Adapter to send back `Fragments`
- In the `getItem()` function, along with returning the fragment add it in an array as well.. this will keep track of instantiated fragments based on their position.
- Now whenever required call `get` the fragment you need, then retrieve the view from that fragment.